# How to edit/write back into a json file?

Tags: java, json

below is my java code to read from a json file

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;



public class FileIO {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //public static Showtime [] movie = MoviesListing.movie();

    public void importTxt() {
        int j = 0;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Glambert/Dropbox/java/New folder/perfection/UPdate/json.txt"));

            for (Object o : a)
            {
                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;

                MoviesListing.movie[j].assign((String) person.get("moviename"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignShowingStatus((String) person.get("showingstatus"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignSynopsis((String) person.get("synopsis"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignDirector((String) person.get("director"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignCast((String) person.get("cast"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignReviewerRate((double) person.get("reviewerRate"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignPastReviews((String) person.get("pastreviews"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignMovieRating((String) person.get("movierating"));
                MoviesListing.movie[j].assignShowtimes((JSONArray) person.get("showtimes"));

                j++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It works from reading a json file like this:

```
[  
  {  
    "moviename":"Goosebumps",
    "showingstatus":"Now Showing",
    "synopsis":"Upset...",
    "director":"Rob Letterman",
    "cast":"Jack Black, Dylan Minnette, Odeya Rush, Amy Ryan",
    "reviewerRate": 3.2 ,
    "pastreviews":"Goosebumps...",
    "movierating":"PG",
    "showtimes":[  
        "09.30",
        "12.30"
    ],
    "job":"Teacher"
  },
  {  
    "moviename":"Bridge of Spies",
    "showingstatus":"Now Showing",
    "synopsis":"Tom Hanks stars..",
    "director":"Steven Spielberg",
    "cast":"Tom Hanks, Mark Rylance",
    "reviewerRate": 3.9,
    "pastreviews":"JBridge...",
    "movierating":"PG-13",
    "showtimes":[  
        "09.40",
        "10.45"
    ],
  }
]
```

However, I want to write/edit into the txt file in the same, or at least close to this format. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON format you have provided, remove the comma after last array:

```
....
"showtimes":[  
    "09.40",
    "10.45"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Solution:**
You can use (Download the Jar file from Maven)
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

And Create a Bean for Your Data as below:

```
MovieBean.java
private String moviename;
private String showingstatus;
...
private ArrayList<Double> showtimes;
private String job;
```

And After that you can use, 
Gson methods `fromJson` and `toJson` for creating JSON to Bean and Bean to JSON respectively.
You can edit the data in Bean and save it again on the same content file.